# File Upload Hangs with Flask

Tags: python, file-upload, upload, flask

I am trying to upload a file but the browser spinner rolls forever, server logs don't show updates and the file doesn't get uploaded. It sure is a newbie error but I have no clue what that is:-

static/index.html :-

```
html
form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
  input type="file" name="db"/
  input type="submit" value="upload"/
/form
html
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from werkzeug import secure_filename

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    print 'upload_file'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print 'post'
        f = request.files['db']
        f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks

Env: Flask 0.9, Jinja2-2.6 and Werkzeug-0.8.3 with Python 2.7 on Win7 x64 with IE9 and Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/fileuploads/) say you should use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Also, I might try `method="POST"` (uppercase), if only because defensive coding is a good habit, the defensive maneuver here being not assuming that Flask is bug-free.

Comment: While the enctype was already multipart/form-data the upcasing seems to have fixed it. Thanks so much.